# CUPS bad request

Tags: linux, cups

I have a little problem with CUPS 2.2.7

This is my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   example.com

127.0.0.1   localhost
```

in http://localhost:631/ CUPS is working right

but in http://example.com:631/ it doesn't work on the same pc.

The message error in **View error log** is that one:

> E [21/Feb/2019:11:54:18 +0100] [Client 33] Request from "localhost" using invalid Host: field "example.com:631".

The web page on Firefox print an error message *Invalid request* and give me an Error (error code: 400) but seems point on CUPS.

How to solve this problem so that example.com:631 points to localhost and CUPS answers it successfully instead of **Error 400: Access Denied**.

Comment: You would have to pass option to CUPS to allow it to service http request for `example.com` host. The hostname is passed via http request to the server too, not only ip is important.

Comment: what option should I pass to do it?

Answer (score 23):

By default cups servers HTTP requests only with HTTP Host header equal to "localhost". To allow it servicing requests for additional HTTP host headers use `ServerAlias` directive as described in the [man cupsd.conf](http://cups.org/doc/man-cupsd.conf.html) documentation. It's common to do the most unsafe thing and add

```
ServerAlias *
```

to `/etc/cupsd.conf` to allow all possible HTTP host headers to be serviced.

Comment: That did not work for me. I still get bad request, even after rebooting.

Comment: it worked for me in combination to Listen *:631

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I too was experiencing the same issue recently and I resolved it by updating the following line in `cupsd.conf` from:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:631
```

changed to:

```
Listen *:631
```

For those that maybe care to know, I'm running CUPS within a docker container, and this change corrects the "Bad Request" response.

Comment: I'm not using Docker, and tried to use your version "Listen *:631", but I'm always having this error [stacktrace=java.io.IOException: HTTP error! Status code:  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. This error happen  when I try to use this call List<CupsPrinter> printers = cupsClient.getPrinters(); 
 Can you or anyone help with that.